# add onChange attribute to a select using jQuery in Joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5

I need to add the onChange attribute to a drop down list using jQuery in Joomla. I have tried the following way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("hello world");
    jQuery("#jform_fkcategory").attr('onChange', 'foo();');
});
```

jQuery is working fine as the alert is popping up. I am unable to add the attribute only. Please help me!

This is my form field:

```
    <field
        name="fkcategory"
        type="category"
        class="inputbox"
        label="Category"
        description=""
        required="true">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
    </field>
```

This is what i've in layout.

```
<select id="jform_fkcategory" name="jform[fkcategory]" class="inputbox required">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  Alter your JavaScript like so:

```
(function($) {

    function foo() {
        $.ajax({
            // place AJAX request params here
        });
    }

    $(document).on('change', '#jform_fkcategory', foo);

})(jQuery);
```

Enclose any code to execute when the onchange event is fired inside the foo function.

Good luck!

Comment: thanx, the function works .... only the thing is that i was looking how i can add the attribute onChange so that i can implement ajax. Something like <select id="jform_fkcategory" name="jform[fkcategory]" class="inputbox required" onChange="foo();">

Comment: This is accomplishes the same thing, and it is considered best practice to keep JavaScript separate HTML.  I edited my answer to show where you can put the AJAX request code.

Comment: thanx onceagain @Brian Bolli, yea i am exactly doing the same thing u ve suggested. Having a tough time how to implement ajax in joomla.

Comment: Here is a link to a great tutorial on the subject, http://docs.joomla.org/JSON_Responses_with_JResponseJson, or post another question and I can help you sort it out :)

Comment: Thank you @Brian Bolli for the tutorial as it looks promising although i already completed the task yesterday. Nevertheless, i will try the tutorial.